# How to decrypt HTTPS traffic on custom TCP port in wireshark

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, wireshark, tcpdump, pki

I am trying to decrypt a pcap file for HTTPS traffic to a non-standard port (38443) using wireshark. I tried setting "SSLKEYLOGFILE", adding the port to the HTTP ports in preferences>protocols, using "Decode as". But I am always getting stuck of failing. What is the straight-forward way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[Quote] https://lekensteyn.nl/files/wireshark-tls-debugging-sharkfest19us.pdf#page=17

Wireshark detects TLS through heuristics, but standard port registrations take
precedence. Use Decode As functionality to set an explicit protocol.

Example: HTTPS on TCP server port 123.

Right-click TCP layer, Decode As. Change current protocol for TCP Port to TLS.

Press OK to apply just for now or Save to persist this port-to-protocol mapping.

Right-click SSL layer, Decode As. Change current protocol for TLS Port to HTTP.

For STARTTLS protocols, select SMTP/IMAP/. . . instead of TLS for TCP Port.

Tip: there are many protocols, just select the field, then use arrow keys or type
the protocol name (typing H gives HTTP)